# Blog Integration and Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

How are you going to integrate with bloggers?

Many contributors have blogs. We write this documentation on our blogs first, then maybe we want to cross post.

For example, CodeProject lets a use integrate easily by posting from a blog feed: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/BlogFeed.aspx

Since posting is going to take away hits from our blog (hence remove Add revenue from us bloggers) how are you going to incentivize us bloggers to contribute here?

Comment: I expect it work similar to how CodeProject works. You setup your blog to integrate. When you post to your blog, it also posts here. As long as there are not significant mods to an article, updates to a blog post would update the article on SO. If there are mods, changes to my blog are merged in. If there are merge conflicts, changes are not merged and a task to manually merge is added to my account.

Comment: We're going to reconstitute our samples from blogs at [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates#). If you're not the owner of the blog entry leave a reference to the original source in any case (May be ask the blog owner for giving permission 1st at all).

Comment: I don't think we want anything to do with bloggers who must get paid or they won't post. It is like saying "I work as consultant in topic x. How will I get paid for answering topic x questions on SO?"

Comment: @Lundin This has nothing to do with answering an SO question. Answering a question and helping out is vastly different than providing free Technical Writing services for the separate Documentation portion of SO.

Comment: How? In one case you write technical text for free, and in the other case you write technical text for free. Prior documentation, SO was already slaughtering blogs to the left and right, particularly the bad ones. Darwinism at its best.

Comment: There is zero difference between "documentation" and the old way of providing "canonical duplicates", except that the latter have far higher quality so far.

Comment: There is a vast difference between general documentation and question/answer documentation.

Answer (score 10):

Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V is the only integration solution that is needed here, IMO.

Anything more complex would likely not work anyway because of license incompatibilities. SO doesn't tolerate dependencies on third party sources in its content (and rightly so), so any content would have to be published here on SO. If it has to be published here on SO, it has to adhere to the CC license.

It seems unlikely that SO would create any other special provisions to allow bloggers to post here and at the same time somehow compensate for lost traffic. They haven't done anything like it in seven years of Q&A.

Rule of thumb: if you don't want to give up control of your blog posts, and don't want to lose the page views on your own blog, don't post them here.

Comment: Completely disagree.

Comment: @Rhyous Why? _"If it has to be published here on SO, it has to adhere to the CC license."_ That's the crucial point: You may need to ask the author for permission, before copying anything from a blog.to SO Documentation examples.

Comment: ... plus blog contributions couldn't be included in the data dump if there's licensing incompatibilities. The data dump is a key element in the site being "community-owned" to some extent. And what if there's community edits to the blog post? This is a non-starter in so many ways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you are confused. I am not talking about publishing someone else's blog. I am talking about a blog owner themselves wanting to cross post to SO.

Comment: There is no CC licensing issue as if a blogger goes through a process of setting up integration, they will have to agree to SO terms and conditions.

Comment: @Rhyous but then I fail to see the advantage of a super complex synchronization mechanism (that would also have to strip out loads of stuff not supported by SO, like video embeds) over good old copy&paste. A sync would be living hell - as said, what if the community wants to edit your contribution? Should those changes be synced back? That's near impossible given the strict limitations on SO's HTML

Comment: @Rhyous You inspired me to try [this out actually](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates?draftId=49216#).

Comment: @Pekka웃 It doesn't have to be complex. Do you have a blog? 

Also, I explained merging in a previous comment. Not that big of a deal at all.

Look, this already works on CodeProject, and no it isn't perfect. But nobody is asking for something that isn't already happening.